# Error 'The request timed out' when uploading files in parallel on AWSS3

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, timeout, aws-sdk

I have a problem with the parallel upload in AWSS3

I'm using

```
AWSTask(forCompletionOfAllTasks:tasks).continueWithBlock({task -> AWSTask in
```

to upload files in parallel on S3. It works well with small amount of file, but when I'm sending more than 50 files in parallel, I have a lot of timeout error and I don't understand why.

I tried several time to load 150 files in parallel and I have a timeout after the 60th file was uploaded with success. There is around 50 timeout error which take around 1 or 2 minutes, after that, the upload continue and at the end all the files are uploaded successfully but these timeout slow a lot the upload...

I see the errors in the logs but I don't know how to catch it in the code, the upload request (AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest) didn't return an error, so I cannot display an error to inform the user that something goes wrong.

Has anybody an idea how to solve the problem? And if there is no solution for the timeout, do you know how to catch the error for at least display an error on the screen?

I already tried to change the timeoutIntervalForRequest/timeoutIntervalForResource but it doesn't change anything.

The error is (fifty times or more):

```
20 AWSiOSSDK v2.4.8 [Error] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:212 | -[AWSURLSessionManager URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:] | Session task failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://s3.amazonaws.com/***/user-72358/project-***/***.jpg?partNumber=1&uploadId=***, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://s3.amazonaws.com/***/user-***/project-***/***.jpg?partNumber=1&uploadId=***, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x1dc69d80 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102}}}
```

And here is my code :

```
func uploadAllFileRequests(imageArray:[String], completion:(filedataReturned:FileData?, uploadOfFileSucceeded: Bool, error: NSError?)-> Void,progress:(totalSent: Int64, totalExpect: Int64)-> Void) -> Void
    {
        var tasks = [AWSTask]()

        let keyCred     = s3CredentialsInfo?.key
        AWSS3TransferManager.registerS3TransferManagerWithConfiguration(serviceConfiguration, forKey: keyCred)
        let transferManager:AWSS3TransferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.S3TransferManagerForKey(keyCred)

        for imageFilePath:String in imageArray {          
            ...

            let keyOnS3     = "\(keyCred!)/\(filename)"

            // url image to upload to s3
            let url:NSURL   = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filedata.getFullpath())

            // next we set up the S3 upload request manager
            let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
            uploadRequest?.bucket = s3CredentialsInfo?.bucket
            uploadRequest?.key = keyOnS3 
            uploadRequest?.contentType = type 
            uploadRequest?.body = url

            // Track Upload Progress through AWSNetworkingUploadProgressBlock
            uploadRequest?.uploadProgress = {(bytesSent:Int64, totalBytesSent:Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend:Int64) in
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    progress(totalSent: currentTotal, totalExpect: totalSize)
                })
            }

            tasks.append(transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock:{task -> AWSTask in
                if(task.result != nil){
                    // upload success
                    print("-> upload successfull \(keyOnS3) on S3")
                    completion(filedataReturned:filedata, uploadOfFileSucceeded: true, error: nil)
                }else{
                    print("->task error upload on S3 : \(task.error)")
                }
                return task
            }))
        }
        AWSTask(forCompletionOfAllTasks:tasks).continueWithBlock({task -> AWSTask in
            print("-> parallel task is \(task)")
            if(!task.cancelled && !task.faulted){
                // upload success
                print("-> upload successfull  on S3")
            }else{
                print("->error of parallel upload on S3")
                completion(filedataReturned:nil, uploadOfFileSucceeded: false, error: task.error)
            }
            return task
        })
    }
```

I'm using AWSCore and AWSS3 cocoapods version 2.4.8

Thanks in advance for your help

Stéphanie

Answer (score 0):

The error of time out comes once your network is slow, for this you just have to increate time out in configuration.

In your case

```
let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: convertedRegion, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
configuration?.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60 // in seconds
```